# XCode 12 - iOS 14 - UIButton IBAction not working

Tags: uibutton, ios14, xcode12

I'm facing a problem with XCode12 in my iPhone XS with iOS 14.
Don't know why, when I execute my app, the IBActions and segues doesn't work. Any of them, but if I launch the app in XCode11.7 (without changing a line of code) all the IBActions and segues work perfectly.

I'm not doing anything special, just UIButton with IBAction or UIButton that triggers a segue directly.

Any idea?

Regards

**Edit (25/09/2020):**

So, I found out that, if the view has some uibutton that triggers a segue directly (*figure 1*), this doesn't work. In fact, if you try to trigger this segue, the rest of the uibuttons that have an IBAction implemented into the ViewController stop working. The rest of the UIButtons with IBActions works since I tap on a UIButton with a direct segue.

FIGURE 1:
[image: figure 1]